# Oracle INSERT performance for large chunks of data

Tags: performance, oracle, insert, bulk

I am developing stored procedure for Oracle 10g and I am hitting pretty heavy performance bottle neck while trying to pass list of about 2-3k items into procedure. Here's my code:

```
TYPE ty_id_list
  AS TABLE OF NUMBER(11);

----------------------------------------------------------


PROCEDURE sp_performance_test (
  p_idsCollection IN schema.ty_id_list )
AS

TYPE type_numeric_table IS TABLE OF NUMBER(11) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
l_ids type_numeric_table;
data type_numeric_table;
empty type_numeric_table;

BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'ALTER TABLE schema.T_TEST_TABLE NOLOGGING';
COMMIT;

SELECT COLUMN_VALUE BULK COLLECT INTO l_ids 
  FROM TABLE(p_idsCollection);

FOR j IN 1 .. l_ids.COUNT LOOP
  data(data.count+1) := l_ids(j);

  IF(MOD(data.COUNT,500) = 0 ) THEN
    FORALL i IN 1 .. data.COUNT
      INSERT INTO schema.T_TEST_TABLE (REF_ID, ACTIVE)
      VALUES (data(i), 'Y');  
  data := empty;
  END IF;
END LOOP;
IF(data.count IS NOT NULL) THEN
  FORALL i IN 1 .. data.COUNT
    INSERT INTO schema.T_TEST_TABLE (REF_ID, ACTIVE)
    VALUES (data(i), 'Y'); 
END IF;
COMMIT;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'ALTER TABLE schema.T_TEST_TABLE LOGGING'; 
COMMIT;

END sp_performance_test;
```

So the thing that adds up to the process quite drastically seems to be this part: data(data.count+1) := **l_ids(j)**; If I skip getting element from the collection and change this line to data(data.count+1) := **j**;, procedure execution time will be 3-4 times faster (from over 30s to 8-9s for 3k items) - but this logic obviously is not the one i want.

Can You guys give me a hint where could I improve my code to get better performance on inserting data? If any improvements can be done really.

Thanks,
Przemek

Comment: Your procedure only takes 0.7 seconds for me, using 3K values on an old desktop PC.  And most of that time is spent parsing my sample data.  This implies either your server is very slow, or there are some other special conditions that are taking up most of the time.
Can you add the table DDL, and a script to generate sample data?  Maybe you don't need to optimize this procedure, perhaps the problem is elsewhere.  For example, maybe there's a trigger slowing down the inserts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow your logic.

You accept a collection. You copy it to another collection:

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE BULK COLLECT INTO l_ids 
  FROM TABLE(p_idsCollection);
```

And then you copy it once again, in a loop:

```
FOR j IN 1 .. l_ids.COUNT LOOP
  data(data.count+1) := l_ids(j);
```

And only after that you manage to perform your 500-row-chunk bulk insert. What is wrong with bulk inserting `p_idsCollection` immediately?

p.s. You don't need commits after 'ALTER TABLE', ddl statements issue them implicitly.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the confusion, the only reason i've done re-writing collection from p_idsCollection to l_ids is to (potentially) take advantage of indexing of type_numeric_table, I am not entirely sure if it makes alot of sense but eventually this operation doesn't add much into the process execution times.
Splitting it to 500-row chunks is just following advices from Oracle 'Ask Tom' thing and seems to speed up inserting A LOT comparing to just FORALL loop on original, complete collection.

Comment: you're not taking any advantage here. this is not an "indexed table", it is an associative array. check out the corresponding doc section: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#i20383

Comment: Thanks for this catch, good to know! But that still doesn't help much with my overall performance unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

that whole block after the DDL can be rewritten as

```
insert into schema.T_TEST_TABLE (REF_ID, ACTIVE) 
select COLUMN_VALUE, 'Y' FROM TABLE(p_idsCollection);
```

Comment: Yeah tried that as a one of very first attempts but performance of INSERT-SELECT seems to be slightly slower than the one of my latest code (split FORALL). Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can also add hint into insert operation.

Insert /*+ append */ into tab (...) values (...)

It's change oracle work logic and it will work faster.

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_insert_tuning.htm